# Java regular expression matching two consecutive consonants

Tags: java, regex, string, regex-greedy

I'm trying to match only strings with two consecutive consonants. but no matter what input I give to myString this never evaluates to true, so I have to assume something is wrong with the syntax of my regex. Any ideas?

```
if (Pattern.matches("([^aeiou]&&[^AEIOU]){2}", myString)) {...}
```

Additional info:

- myString is a substring of at most two characters
- There is no whitespace, as this string is the output of a .split with a whitespace delimiter
- I'm not worried about special characters, as the program just concatenates and prints the result, though if you'd like to show me how to include something like [b-z]&&[^eiou] in your answer I would appreciate it.

Edit:
After going through these answers and testing a little more, the code I finally used was

```
if (myString.matches("(?i)[b-z&&[^eiou]]{2}")) {...}
```

Comment: Do you have a character that's not "a", "e", "i", "o", or "u", followed by "&&", followed by a character that's not "A", "E", "I", "O", or "U", followed by the same thing again (i.e. repeated twice)?

Comment: If you're using  `&&` you need to place your intersections inside a bracketed expression. `[a-z&&[^aeiou]]{2}`

Comment: Thanks to everyone!

I picked dasblink's answer because it was older, met my optional parameter of only taking actual letters, his Demo link was really helpful for understanding the usage of compiled Patterns, and finally - I completely understood it right away.

Once again though, all of you helped, and if had enough rep to upvote I would have at least done that for some of the other answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[^aeiou]` matches non-letter characters as well, so you should use a different pattern:

```
Pattern rx = Pattern.compile("[bcdfghjklmnpqrstuvwxyz]{2}", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
if (rx.matches(myString)) {...}
```

If you would like to use `&&` for an intersection, you can do it like this:

```
"[a-z&&[^aeiou]]{2}"
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/FhvAgi)

Comment: @Pshemo Ah, that's what he was trying to do! That makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To use character class intersection, you need to wrap your syntax inside of a bracketed expression. The below matches characters that are both lowercase letters and not vowels.

```
[a-z&&[^aeiou]]{2}
```

Comment: I don't know why but I don't like idea of placing `a` into character set just to remove it right away :/ I know this makes regex easier to understand, but still `[b-z&&[^eiou]]` seems cleverer :)

Comment: @Pshemo I like the way you think =)